# Opposite of fork()

Tags: merge, process, fork, wait

When we have a process, regardless of the programming language we usually have a call `fork()` or similar to tell the OS we want the process to be splitted.

The child **inherits the state** and continues on. We can detach it or not, etc.

Usually we use `wait()` or similar to monitor that another process ended.

The question is: Is there a function like "opposite" of `fork()` to **merge** two processes in one? This would like **import and merge** the state of the child process.

I can easily see it in "git branches": You are working on branch A, you create a branch B, do changes on A, you do changes in B and then you merge either B into A or A into B. Imagine you merge B into A: provided that there are no conflicts (which is not always guaranteed) you end up with one single branch A that "imports" the work done in B, not just "waited B to end".

Does the concept apply to operating system processes also? What function is there in any language to do this?